# Scroll not working

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

I'm trying to use `angular2-perfect-scrollbar`.

I'm using it in div, it works but at the end of the div main scroll should work, it is not working.

When the content of the div ends main scroll should work.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OptionsComponent } from './options/options.component';
import { InclusionsComponent } from './inclusions/inclusions.component';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OptionsComponent,
    InclusionsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG)
  ],
  providers: [QuoteService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**inclusions.component.ts** (where I'm trying to use perfect scroll)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';
@Component({
  selector: 'inclusions',
  templateUrl: './inclusions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inclusions.component.css']
})
export class InclusionsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
   }
    ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**inclusions.component.html**

```
<div class="item active">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="inclusions_bx_detail">
               <div class="inclusions_bx_detail_title">
                  <div class="inclusions_bx_detail_title_icon">
                     <img src="assets/images/inclusions_icon1.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <h3>hotel stay information</h3>
                  <span>Accomodation And Dining</span>
               </div>
               <div class="inclusions_detail_img ">
                  <img src="assets/images/inclusions_img1.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
               <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info "  [perfect-scrollbar]="config">
                  <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                     <img src="assets/images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                     <span>2 Nights in Pattaya (Day 1, 2)</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                     <img src="assets/images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                     <span>2 Nights in Bangkok (Day 3, 4)</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inclusions_detail_img_info_in">
                     <img src="assets/images/inclusions_img_icon1.png" alt="">
                     <span>4 ABFs (Day 1, 2, 3 ,4)</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DhavalMarthak added `app.module.ts` `inclusions.component.ts` and `inclusions.component.html`